# WCF service inside a WCF service. What can I do about the DataContracts?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I'm making a WCF service that only exists to help the caller reach another WCF service. In other words, my service receive data and send (the same data) to the other service. I will call my service as service A and the other service as service B.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ServiceB
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SendComplexData(ComplexData data);
}

[DataContract]
class ComplexData { ... }
```

In the service B I call a method with a complex type as parameter, exposed to me by the DataContract. The question is, should I, in my service A, request the data in the same B type? And, if yes, how can I exposed this existing type to the caller?

```
[ServiceContract]
public Interface ServiceA
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SendComplexDataToServiceB(ComplexData data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I request the data ...

This is one of the options, the easier one. Another option is to expose a different contract and cincert between the two in your proxy service A.

Which option you pick depends on your and your client requirements.

> How can I expose the type to the caller?

By reusing the very same type in your method's signature. How technically the client uses the type, depends on the client. Basically there are three options:

- client relies on WSDL metadata and generates the class code at his/her side
- client gets an assembly that contains the type
- client gets the source code of the type

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should I put the [DataContract] in the reference.cs file?

Comment: And what is `reference.cs`?

Comment: When adding the service B reference to my project a Reference.cs is created with the code associated with the service. In this file I can find the `ComplexData`, for example. So, in this generated file, should I put the `[DataContract]` so can I expose this class through my service?

Comment: Ok, that's one of options. Another option is to create a shared assembly that contains the type and reference **the very same** assembly in A and B. Then, when you create a reference to B in A, just remember to check the "reuse types from referenced assemblies". This way the generated proxy class **will not** contain the type definition as the type from the referenced shared assembly will be used. You could then use the same assembly once again, when you create a client of the service A.